# Как использовать Модели машинного обучения в Android?

Tags: java, android, python, машинное-обучение

Есть модель машинного обучения, которая может сравнивать картинки и говорить, это она или нет. Написано на Python. Могу ли я свою модель внедрить в Android без использования сторонних библиотек типа Firebase и т.п?

Comment: https://medium.com/@elye.project/applying-tensorflow-in-android-in-4-steps-to-recognize-superhero-f224597eb055

Comment: а если у меня keras ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=is+keras+part+of+tensorflow%3F ;)

Comment: неудачнй пример )))я хотел сказать skitlearn или как он там

Comment: не знаю - надо гуглить... )